# How to hide routes in address bar in angular 5+?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5

**I want to hide routes from browser's address bar.**
Ex: 
**http://localhost:4200/user/profile**

to
**http://localhost:4200**

can we hide routes?

Comment: The whole point is precisely to **have** a different URL in the address bar, and thus allow using the back button, bookmarking a page, sending a URL in an email, etc. Don't piss off the users of your app. Respect how the web is supposed to work.

Comment: Simple!! Don't use the angular router!

Comment: It's possible. we can store the current URL in local storage. but if any option available or not instead of this?

Comment: Why would you ever do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding : `{ skipLocationChange: true })` after navigation.

Read more about navigation extras [here](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) .

I created the following [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-ll6cqj) that shows how to achieve what you are looking for.

**As mentioned in comments, This feature is not recommended.**